# K-Means clustering with low silhouette score but clear cluster pattern, what to believe

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means, unsupervised-learning, silhouette

Thanks all in advance! I'm pretty new in unsupervised learning.

I have a web usage dataset with inflated zeros. The zeros are simply because user didn't engage with a web feature. The usages are relatively low for majority of my variables.

I clustered my data with K-Means, the silhouette score looks not very convincing as it looks like I only one good cluster and it's really big:[image]. The plots are number of clusters and silhouette score from 2 to 5 clusters.

It looks like the 3 clusters have higher score. I went ahead to cluster with k=3. If I plot a polar plot, it looks like the clusters are very clear. [image]

I'm really confused, are my clustered result valid or not?

Comment: Did you try the elbow method? Check out the link below and see if it helps you.

https://notebook.community/DistrictDataLabs/yellowbrick/examples/gokriznastic/Iris%20-%20clustering%20example

Comment: @ASH I did. I tried elbow method using both inertia and distortion. Elbow using inertia suggests 2 and distortion suggests 5. My question is if my clustered results look distinct but the silhouette score is not. What should I believe?

Comment: The silhouette score of 1 means that the clusters are very dense and nicely separated. The score of 0 means that clusters are overlapping. The score of less than 0 means that data belonging to clusters may be wrong/incorrect.

Comment: What is your polar plot showing us?  Is that the mean for each variable for the three clusters,  or something else?